# CakePHP how to set conditions on contain table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 2 tables, Drivers and Cars. The Drivers table hasMany association with cars. I created a controller called SearchController. In search controller I load the Driver model using $this->loadModel('Drivers');

When I enter a search, I want it to only return cars that are automatic and the drivers details but it is returning all values including cars which are not automatic.

```
$drivers = $this->paginate($this->Drivers, [
        'contain' => ['Cars']], [
        'conditions' => ['Cars.transmission' => 'Automatic'] ] );  

 $this->set(compact('drivers')); 
 $this->set('_serialize', ['drivers']);
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

**---EDIT----**

The statement I want to achieve is :

```
SELECT * FROM drivers, cars 
         WHERE drivers.id = cars.driver_id 
         AND cars.transmission = 'Automatic'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write your contain like this:

```
'contain' => [
    'Cars' => function($query){
        return $query->where(['transmission' => 'Automatic']);
    }
]
```

For more options, please refer to CakePHP cookbook: [Passing Conditions to Contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain)

**EDIT**:

To select only Drivers that have Cars with "Automatic" transmission, and to select list of those cars for each driver, you need to join these two tables together. Result code should look like this:

```
$query = $this->Drivers->find()
            ->matching("Cars", function($q){
                return $q->where(["Cars.transmission" => "Automatic"]);
            })
            ->contain([
                "Cars" => function ($q) {
                    return $q->where(["transmission" => "Automatic"]);
                }
            ]);

$result = $this->paginate($query);
```

`matching()` used here will join tables drivers and cars, and set condition accordingly. `contain()` part of query is still the same.

For more options, please visit these docs:

[Pagination](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html)

[Retrieving Data & Results Sets](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This statement is returning all drivers including those with Manual car but the car object for drivers with Manual is empty. Is it possible to do it the same way I would directly on sql.. i.e

    SELECT * FROM `drivers`, cars WHERE drivers.id = cars.driver_id and cars.transmission = 'Automatic' 

Which only returns drivers with Automatic cars only.

Answer (score 3):

Additional associations can be loaded to the paginated table by using the `contain` parameter:

```
$this->paginate['contain'] = [
    'Cars' => function (\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
        return $query->where(['Cars.transmission' => 'Automatic']);
    }
];

$drivers = $this->paginate($this->Drivers);  

$this->set(compact('drivers')); 
$this->set('_serialize', ['drivers']);
```

**See also**

- [Joining Additional Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html#joining-additional-associations)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This statement is returning all drivers including those with Manual car but the car object for drivers with Manual is empty. Is it possible to do it the same way I would directly on sql.. i.e

    SELECT * FROM `drivers`, cars WHERE drivers.id = cars.driver_id and cars.transmission = 'Automatic'

Comment: It is the right way, I Do not know why it is not working.